# can you assign draggable like how you add events to a arb node and a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

You can do something like:

```
 function myFunct(){/*.....*/}
 $("body").on("click", "li.itemlist", function(){
     alert("ping");
 });
```

which would have all li.itemlist under body to have the click event.

Is there a way to convert:

```
 var _OPTIONS_ = {
     containment: "#stage", 
     start:function(){/*...*/}, 
     drag:function(){/*...*/}, 
     stop:function(){/*...*/} 
 };

 $("li.itemlist").draggable(_OPTIONS_);
```

to:

```
 $("body").on("draggable", "li.itemlist", _OPTIONS_);
```

EDIT:  I have not tried the second one.  I didnt think it would work because draggable is a JQuery function, not a standard js listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but there is another way to do it.

```
$("body").on("mouseenter","li.itemlist:not(.draginit)",function(){
    $(this).draggable(_OPTIONS_).addClass("draginit");
})
```

The first time the element is moused over, the draggable widget will be applied to it.

I'd suggest using something better than `body` though, such as the `ul`.

Comment: I did not think of that idea.  Thats actually pretty smart, assuming that _OPTTIONS_ is static and doesnt change.  Was usign the body as an example.  Not used in actual implementation to give enough contrast for people to understand

Comment: You can still modify `_OPTIONS_` inside the event handler if needed.